# Azure VM, All passwords changed on login

Tags: virtual-machines, windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop, azure, password

We've got an Azure VM running Server 2012 R2. I have to stress that this is NOT a classic machine.

I installed server essentials yesterday and linked all the accounts to an O365 account. A by product of this process was a message that said something to the effect of "..You will have to change your password on the next login..". This message was repeated for all the users on the server including mine. I thought nothing more of it.

We shut down for the night. When I tried to login this morning, **I get a message that says "you must change your password before logging on the first time" and then the connection bombs out. This happens to all the users on the server.**

So now all my users are locked out and my poor system administration is to blame.

I've wasted a whole day trying to sort this out, What should my next step be?

I've tried;

1)
Googling the hell out of it. Apparently it's a known problem..

2)
Resetting the the credentials for the VM via Portal.azure.com but the service is "coming soon" for "new" (not classic) VMs.

3)
Using the PowerShell Interface to change the password but because the VM isn't a classic machine the option isn't avalible to even select the machine. (It doesn't belong to a cloud service?) (I can see it when I use the Get-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment but I can't grab it with Get-AzureVM)

4)
Opening a service request, but I'm 99% sure he's gonna blow me off as it's kinda my own fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use Powershell ARM cmdlets:

Download from: http://aka.ms/webpi-azps

```
PS C:\> Login-AzureRmAccount
PS C:\> Set-AzureRmVMAccessExtension -ResourceGroupName RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME -Name HOSTNAME -VMName VM_NAME -UserName USER -Password PASSWORD
```

You can also use the CLI:

Download from: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/xplat-cli-install/

```
> azure login
> azure config mode arm
> azure vm reset-access -g RESORCE_GROUP_NAME -n VM_NAME -u USER -p PASSWORD
```

Comment: Holy Smokes. You're a hero. If I every meet you, I'll buy you a pint.